# Why can I link two libraries exporting the same C-Function in VC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the situation that two C++ Libraries export the very same C-function symbols from shared code. When I now compile an executable which links both libraries, I do not get any linker error or warning from VC12. Why is this? It silently just chooses one of the two symbols and I have no idea which one is chosen.;

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) int function(void* argument);}
```

There is a flag named /FORCE which whould be able to convice VC to compile even if there are multiply defined symbols, but this flag is not set.

I do not find any official information from Microsoft why this links at all. I was expecting to get a LNK4006 warning, but I don't.

1. I just want to know if this is the expected or undefined behavior, which only did not explode by coincidence. I read things about the One Definition Rule not being applied generally to C-Code, but I cannot find any reliable statement for the VC compiler.
2. Can I assume that, given the functions do not use any singletons, use the very same code and compiler flags, it does not matter which one is chosen?

Comment: Because you are violating ODR rule, and this is undefined behavior. No diagnostic is required.

Comment: Visual Studio is allowed to warn you.  Unfortunately, many people disable that particular warning because you get false positives when functions include a lot of templates.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the **one definition rule**.
The behavior of you program is undefined.

See section "*3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]*" in the C++ standard.

> 4. Every program shall contain **exactly one definition of every non-inline function** or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. ...

Section 3.2.6 describes when there can be **more than one definition**
of a class type, inline function with external linkage etc. in a program.

---

> 1. I just want to know if this is the expected or undefined behavior, which only did not explode by coincidence. I read things about the One Definition Rule not being applied generally to C-Code, but I cannot find any reliable statement for the VC compiler.

- It is undefined behavior.
- The C++ standard is the master, not the VC compiler.

> 2. Can I assume that, given the functions do not use any singletons, use the very same code and compiler flags, it does not matter which one is chosen?

- It is still undefined behavior - though the program might appear to behave as expected.